# Should I close output stream if I get FileNotFoundException? And IOException?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
   private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Do I need to close the `FileOutputStream` in `FileNotFoundException` catch block?

If that exception is thrown means that file could not be opened so I think that it would not be necessary. However, I think it would be nice to do it in `IOException` catch block.

Could it cause any memory leak error or something similar if I don't do it?

Thanks.

Comment: In that case fos is not opened and fos will be null. So there is nothing to close. Please try.

Comment: @greenapps Not null, just never assigned, and out of scope in the `catch` block.

Comment: You should start with `FileOutputStream fos = null;` outside the catch block of course..

Comment: Ohhh... that was you EJP. This will be a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in Java 7 or above you should use a *try with resources* and let the system decide.

```
private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If not then just ensure that the stream is not `null` first and do it in a `finally`.

```
private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to close. The `FileOutputStream` constructor threw an exception; the stream was never constructed; the `fos` variable has never been assigned; and it is out of scope in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

You should always close the file once you have finished to read or write. Otherwise you will keep the resource busy and in general could be a problem.
If you modify your code in this way you will not have to care about close the file and java will think about it.

```
    private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
       try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, fos);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. You can't do any reading or writing if there was a `FileNotFoundException`, or any closing either.